# How to start the home activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write a class `BaseActivity` to handle a couple of generic behaviours.

One of them is to catch the click on the application icon and to rederict to the first activity.
This sounds simple, but this `BaseActivity` will be in a library project. I cannot use an explicit intent (defined by a class). Instead I'm trying to use a generic intent:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        // app icon in action bar clicked: go back home
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting an `ActivityNotFoundException` and I don't understand why.

What can I do?

Comment: It looks like you don't set an activity, just the package

Comment: @zapl if I don't set the package, then all applications are possible candidates of the intent resolution. I need to add a filter for my app, somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are searching for [`getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) from the `PackageManager`. It takes the package name as as a parameter and creates an `Intent` to launch that package's main activity. In this way, you don't need to indicate the specific class that should be launched within the package.

> The current implementation will look first for a main activity in the
>   category `CATEGORY_INFO`, next for a main activity in the category
>   `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, or return null if neither are found.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to do, and the `PackageManage` build that kind of intents better than I do